# how does wifi routers detect remote client mac address?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I read questions about `accessing client mac address` using `JavaScript/JQuery` then almost every answer says that it is security risk and needs client permission. But when we open the setup of `wifi router` e.g `TPLINK` etc, then there are options of `mac-filtering` and other similar options using client mac address.And client mac addresses are clearly visible on there setup page which we access remotly when we connect our device with them using  wifi. Pardon me if my question is too foolish.

Comment: The fact that you can access your router through a web interface doesn't mean it does everything in a web environment, it's probably just displaying it there.

Comment: Florian F. You are right. I was assuming it a web interface

Answer (score 1):

The router is on the same LAN as the computer it is detecting the MAC address of and it is doing it with server side code (which probably looks at the routing table generated by the router software), not client-side JavaScript.